# FacesFileNotFoundException

Tags: jsf

I am trying to build a basic facelets application however i am getting following Exception

> com.sun.faces.context.FacesFileNotFoundException
>     com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletFactory.resolveURL(DefaultFaceletFactory.java:232)
>     com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletFactory.resolveURL(DefaultFaceletFactory.java:273)
>     com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletFactory.getMetadataFacelet(DefaultFaceletFactory.java:209)
>     com.sun.faces.application.view.ViewMetadataImpl.createMetadataView(ViewMetadataImpl.java:114)
>     com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RestoreViewPhase.execute(RestoreViewPhase.java:230)
>     com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
>     com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RestoreViewPhase.doPhase(RestoreViewPhase.java:113)
>     com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
>     javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:409)

I am passing correct url and has also mapped the servlet requests to .xhtml in web.xml

Comment: Please post what user action is triggering this, what the url is, and where the file is in your web content.

Comment: I have placed header.xhtml,footer.xhtml,content.html and layout.xhtml in a folder called template in WEB-INF. and a mainPage.xhtml page calls this layout. when i am entering the url http://localhost:8080/trying_facelets/mainPage.xhtml it is giving the above mentioned Exception

Comment: Perhaps your ui:composition tag is not pointing to the correct place.  Here is an example of what it should look like, `<ui:composition template="/WEB-INF/template/dashboardTemplate.xhtml">`

Comment: My <ui:composition> tag is <ui:composition template="/WEB-INF/template/layout.xhtml"> seems all right, still getting the same exception